# How to attach debugger in chrome extension along with selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, selenium, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**Goal:** I want to run an experiment in which I will open a list of websites and want to collect the scripts that are parsed on those websites. The way I plan to do is as follows:

- using [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) I will open each website in chrome.
- using [chrome.debugger api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) I will attach a debugger and listen to [Debugger.Scriptparsed](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/Debugger/) event.

**Problem:** When I open a website in a chrome (loaded with my extension ) with selenium, it throws an error that another debugger is also attached to tab. I read [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients#webdriver), it states that selenium webdriver is using debugger also. In that case is there a way to use [these](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/Debugger/) functions with selenium webdriver for chrome only?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the webdriver itself is working through the debugging protocol and you cannot use the `chrome.debugger API` or open the developer tools in the browser that is automated with selenium.

Comment: Thanks but I much I understand browsermob is for collecting network requests. Here I am trying to get [parsed scripts](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/Debugger/#event-scriptParsed) . Is it possible to achieve this with browsermob?

Comment: @muhammadharis yeah, you are right. Removed the irrelevant part of the answer. I'll look into it more and see if there is any other way. Thanks.